# What will happen when all the possible answers are given to all possible questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, fun

What will happen when all the possible answers are given to all possible questions?

Comment: Its always Friday in Iceland, even on Friday

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20620/are-questions-in-stackoverflow-slowing

Comment: When that happens, there will be more questions and suggestions on how to deal with that situation. That itself self-generates whole new world of new problems/questions to be solved.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19238/could-we-ever-get-to-the-stage-where-almost-everything-is-answered

Answer (score 56):

We'll all hold our monitors upside-down and shake them so we can start over.

Comment: FTW (nothing more to say here...)

Comment: Do we all have to do it at the same time?  I just tried it and the questions are still there.

Answer (score 32):

We'll get very good at clicking "vote to close as duplicate".

Comment: Or else all questions will automatically be marked as *Possible duplicate of some other damn question*.

Answer (score 26):

Jon Skeet will put some ice on his wrists. That was a lot of typing.

Comment: Actually, the ice will put itself on his wrists out of pity.

Answer (score 25):

**That will never happen.**

But, when it does, there will be balloons. And cake. And maybe champagne, if we can get Jeff to spring for it. Otherwise, it's BYOB - I recommend something light, the cake will be too sweet (it's *always* too sweet).

Comment: The cake is a lie!

Comment: @Farseeker want some? It's lovely!

Comment: This was a triumph!

Comment: Bring your own balloons!

Answer (score 19):

[INSUFFICIENT DATA FOR MEANINGFUL ANSWER.](http://www.multivax.com/last_question.html)

Answer (score 15):

We'll never know because the SO search is so bad the duplicates will never be found.

Answer (score 13):

Fire and brimstone coming down from the sky! Rivers and seas boiling!

Forty years of darkness! Earthquakes, volcanoes...

The dead rising from the grave!

Human sacrifice. Dogs and cats living together. Mass hysteria!

Answer (score 13):

At that point the universe throws a Stack Overflow exception, and Jon Skeet's reputation is set to zero.

Answer (score 6):

We will finally know the Ultimate Question that goes along with the Ultimate Answer.

Comment: __42__.  (what, you were thinking of another Ultimate Answer?)

Answer (score 5):

We will beat entropy

Comment: _/me prefers to whip it, whip it good_

Answer (score 4):

The shear mass of questions will collapse in upon themselves, forming a black hole which will envelop our entire existence.  Once everything has collapsed to a singularity, a big bang will occur, and it will all start over again.

Either that or a rain drop will fall in the Sahara.

One can never calculate the outcome with 100% certainty, you know.

Comment: I always wondered how the universe began, what was before the Big Bang. Now I know... These was a Stack Overflow in the previous universe too.
Wait, I think Joel and Jeff knew that! Don't you get their irony? Clue: What happens to a host programme when a stack overflows?