# Is StackOverflow getting full?

Tags: discussion, community, development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What will happen when all the possible answers are given to all possible questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31134/what-will-happen-when-all-the-possible-answers-are-given-to-all-possible-questio)

For the past couple of year, every programming related problem I have ran into has an answer in StackOverflow.
I ask the question in http://www.google.com and SO pops up as the first resolution which usually also is the most helping resource there is in the interweb. Asking new questions is pointless since everything is already answered.

The biggest question is, why is it like that?
I have few assumptions and maybe the community can help to pick the best one:

- New, emerging development tools are easier to use and better documented than old ones (compare C, PHP, Python, Ruby, Node.js) so questions are answered without community based sophisticated knowledge base

  New technologies appear and are adapted less agile than before and therefore questions just don't pop up

  Development of application has became so agile that developers choose to select tools that they know instead of trying new ones

  ... something else...

The question could sound like a troll but I think that in longer run getting to know the answer could give some whole new meaning to community based knowledge base like StackOverflow.

Answer (score 7):

You greatly underestimate the number of mistakes waiting to be made.

Comment: Thanks God there's only one Jon Skeet out there!
...or was it the other way round?

Answer (score 4):

While I'd like it to be true that all questions are answered on Stack Overflow, I don't think we're really there, or ever will be.  There are thousands of questions a day asked on Stack Overflow,  so the pace isn't really slowing down.

Comment: I would love to know if the ratio of good/bad quality questions has changed over time (assuming we have the data).

Comment: @oded this question looks into the idea of quantifying question quality http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109974/is-it-possible-to-quantify-the-quality-of-questions-over-time

Comment: To say nothing of the fact that new frameworks and libraries—about which new questions can be asked—are constantly being created.

Comment: And of course, there's never a shortage of new products under "I'm a programmer" so giv meh teh codez